What makes a MCU capable of higher temps than another?
Just an example - STM32F722 has a few versions, but I'm talking about just the variance between two numbers: RET6 vs RET7.  The former has a max operating temp of 85C, whereas the latter says 105C.  My question is, on a technical level:  What might be the difference between the two that makes the RET7 capable of a higher operating temperature, where the entire rest of the chip's functionality is indistinguishable to the other in every other way?  Do they space "parts" of the chip further apart?  Do they have a different node size?  Something else?  This is purely curiosity.

The temperatures are relatively low, silicon-wise and may be due to non-volatile memory. I honestly don't know in this case -- will read answers. So can only guess from business considerations. They must perceive (or know about) a customer where the 20 C bump is important (could be automotive as they are big enough buyers.) Could either be binning from non-volatile memory testing results or something special done. The "something special" would cost more. The "binning" is a question mark as I'm not sure what kind of memory testing might present such a demarcation. Interesting question. I'll +1.

They're probably the same except the testing limits for the higher temperature version would be tighter since they have to allow for more change in order to guarantee proper operation at the higher limits.
Parts designed for actual extreme temperatures such as this 8051 derivative which can operate to 225°C with guaranteed characteristics and (it is suggested) typically to 300°C (572°F) with degraded performance for a year or so are made with some process and design changes (dielectric rather than junction isolation is one difference they mention). No non-volatile memory is provided. Naturally that kind of thing is a bit expensive, especially when made for niche markets, which pushes the price up two or three orders of magnitude.

We probably can't know for sure for any particular device, short of the manufacturer saying so*.  But it is common industry practice that a given chip design is tested for different parameters (including temperature), and binned and sold accordingly.
*And at that, since it literally doesn't matter for any conceivable end use, I wouldn't put much confidence in anything a lower-tier engineer (FAE etc.) says; they might just be answering to close your ticket and move on to the next.  Most confident would be technology exchange under license, i.e. engaging with a manufacturer to use their fab for custom products.
Normal process variation includes a range in Vgs(th), W and L, resulting in variable current capacity, capacitance, speed (gm per capacitance), and voltage range.  And, more for bipolar processes, voltage limits vary, because diffusion of dopants is hard to control precisely (or more particularly, behavior is highly sensitive to doping concentration and gradient, so it needs to be incredibly precise) and that determines breakdown voltage.  (Back in the day, you might've had a family of BJTs, often sequential part numbers, rated for example 60, 80, 100V; or 160, 200, 250V, or... And actual bogeys might break down at anything from 100 to 350V or more. Nowadays, they're usually pretty well controlled, so that a 100V MOSFET might break down at 120-160V.)
Temperature limits are also defined by design and testing.  A design might simply not meet specs outside the temp range, but otherwise function normally.  Or it might malfunction, even catastrophically.  Accounting for parameter variation with both temperature range and process variation, is part of the design process, and operating outside the design range can simply be whatever -- all you know is it's not controlled.
Likewise, temperature range can be evaluated in wafer test or packaging, though I don't know how and when they prefer to do this and I would guess they prefer to do spot testing, as performance will be largely similar across the wafer, or by region on the wafer.

One other thing to add is packaging - the plastic of the IC has to maintain its mechanical properties at the higher temp - it may not make much difference from 85C to 105C, but it might for 125C and above -

Indeed, and plastic is unsuitable by 150-175C (even for power transistors). Packaging stresses are also a factor in precision circuits, to the extent that there are (manufacturer-)programmable devices trimmed after packaging but before finishing lead frame cuts. Higher temp and some precision devices still use ceramic and metal packaging.
